# Error msg: subscript out of bounds in R with examples

Tags: r, dataframe, quantmod

I am working with below lines:

```
y<-c(1,59,60,65,85,86,1550,97)
z<-c(1:8)
test<-cbind(y,z)

> test
        y z
[1,]    1 1
[2,]   59 2
[3,]   60 3
[4,]   65 4
[5,]   85 5
[6,]   86 6
[7,] 1550 7
[8,]   97 8

view_window <- function(dfr, var, x, pm){
  
  idx <- which(abs(test[, var]-x) == min(abs(test[, var] - x)))
  
  return(dfr[(idx - pm) : (idx + pm), ])
  
}

result<-view_window(dfr=test,
            var="y",
            x=83,
            pm=2)


> result
        y z
[1,]   60 3
[2,]   65 4
[3,]   85 5
[4,]   86 6
[5,] 1550 7
```

The example above works well until I used the data frame:

```
#required libiaries

library(quantmod)
library(pedquant)

# download option chain from yahoo finance, using an example of ticker "BABA" & exp= "2023-06-23"
ticker<-c("BABA")
options<-getOptionChain(ticker,Exp="2023-06-23")

# seperate call/put options and display only Strike, Last Price, Volume
call_option<-options$calls[,c("Strike","Last","Vol")]
put_option<-options$puts[,c("Strike","Last","Vol")]

#getting the updated stock price to filter at-the-money level 

ticker_price<-md_stock(ticker,type="real")
price<-ticker_price$close

view_window <- function(dfr, var, x, pm){
  
  idx <- which(abs(test[, var]-x) == min(abs(test[, var] - x)))
  
  return(dfr[(idx - pm) : (idx + pm), ])
  
}

view_window(dfr=call_option,
            var=call_option$Strike,
            x=price,pm=3)

Error in test[, var] : subscript out of bounds
```

Any ideas on solving the subscript out of bounds issue here? Many thanks for your help.

**User-defined function/ user case 1 (working)/ user case 2(not working)**

```
 # user defined function
    
    view_window <- function(dfr, var, x, pm){
      
      idx <- which(abs(dfr[, var]-x) == min(abs(dfr[, var] - x)))
      
      return(dfr[(idx - pm) : (idx + pm), ])
      
    }
    
    #test data set 1
    
    y<-c(1,59,60,65,85,86,1550,97)
    z<-c(1:8)
    test<-cbind(y,z)
    
    view_window(dfr=test,
                var="y",
                x=84.5,
                pm=2)

> view_window(dfr=test,
+             var="y",
+             x=84.5,
+             pm=2)
        y z
[1,]   60 3
[2,]   65 4
[3,]   85 5
[4,]   86 6
[5,] 1550 7


#test data set 2 

#required libiaries

library(quantmod)
library(pedquant)

# download option chain from yahoo finance, using an example of ticker "BABA" & exp= "2023-06-23"
ticker<-c("BABA")
options<-getOptionChain(ticker,Exp="2023-06-23")
test_2<-options$calls[,c("Strike","Last","Vol")]

#getting the updated stock price to filter at-the-money level

ticker_price<-md_stock(ticker,type="real")
price<-ticker_price$close
```

For some reason, I am not able to copy the error msg, however, the only one difference between user case 1 & 2 is that in case 2, instead of using "y" as var, I use test_2$Strike to be var.

Comment: This is likely a typo. Your user-defined function `view_window()` still has `test` as the dataset instead of what I assume should be `dfr`?

Comment: @jpsmith Hi there, tried to replace test with dfr, however still not working.  Many thank you for pointing out though.

Comment: Could you provide more information than “Still not working”? Is it the same issue? A different one?

Comment: #jpsmith sorry it took me a bit, for some reason I cant copy the error msg but it is a different one, please find above cleaner versions of 2 user cases for your ref. Again, many thanks for your help.